# How can I use MarkableIterator in Hadoop?

Tags: java, hadoop

**Background:**
`MarkableIteratorInterface` is an interface for an iterator that supports mark-reset functionality. Basically, you can iterate over the Reducer's values multiple times my "marking" a position and "resetting" back to it. The data is temporarily cached to memory (and then to disk when memory becomes full).

This is possible if the `Reducer`'s `ValueIterator` implements `MarkableIteratorInterface` - that depends upon the Hadoop implementation. [`MarkableIterator`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/MarkableIterator.html) is a wrapper that's used by the client reducer code to iterate (and reiterate) over the values.

Here's the JIRA issue about the feature: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-5266.

**Problem:**
I cannot find a way to use this functionality. The only mention of the actual code I found is on a [branch on Apache's svn](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/pre-HADOOP-4687/src/mapred/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/ReduceContext.java). I cannot seem to find a single version of a Hadoop distribution, be it from Cloudera or just vanilla Hadoop, that allows this. I've been checking on grepcode for a while. Every task fails with the error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Input Iterator not markable`.

Is the only way around this to manually patch the source code and re-compile? Any clues?

**Something interesting:**

- Doing a `grep -R 'implements MarkableIteratorInterface' src/.` in the
  hadoop tarball's root (scroll below to see version details) does NOT
  reveal a `ValueIterator` that implements `MarkableIteratorInterface`,
  as is already evident from grepcode.com
- Also, in http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/cdh/4/hadoop/hadoop/common/CHANGES.txt and http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/CHANGES.txt if you search for "HADOOP-5266", you'll find the entry under NEW FEATURES for Release 0.21.0 - 2010-08-13. What does this even mean? I'll have to download that release from somewhere and I cannot use any cloudera distribution? But that wouldn't have lots of new features from Hadoop 2.0.0 (like being able to use `CompositeInputFormat` from the new MR API for example).

**pom.xml contents:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.nileshc</groupId>
    ...
    ...
    <name>blah</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.16</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>cloudera</id>
            <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-cdh4.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**Reducer reduce method code:**
@Override

```
protected void reduce(LongWritable key, Iterable<CustomWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    MarkableIterator<CustomWritable> itr = new MarkableIterator<CustomWritable>(values.iterator());
    //Error caused in line above
    itr.mark();

    // Compute something
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        // blah blah...
    }
```

}

**Stack trace:**

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/hadoop2/share/hadoop/mapreduce1/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/hadoop2/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
14/01/31 00:29:35 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
14/01/31 00:29:39 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
14/01/31 00:29:39 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 2
14/01/31 00:29:40 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201401302213_0004
14/01/31 00:29:42 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
14/01/31 00:30:02 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 50% reduce 0%
14/01/31 00:30:25 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0%
14/01/31 00:31:29 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 33%
14/01/31 00:31:32 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 50%
14/01/31 00:31:33 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 83%
14/01/31 00:31:53 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201401302213_0004_r_000000_0, Status : FAILED
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Input Iterator not markable
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.MarkableIterator.<init>(MarkableIterator.java:45)
    at com.nileshc.graphfu.pagerank.Driver$MyReducer.reduce(Driver.java:185)
    at com.nileshc.graphfu.pagerank.Driver$MyReducer.reduce(Driver.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:164)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:610)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:444)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)

attempt_201401302213_0004_r_000000_0: SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
attempt_201401302213_0004_r_000000_0: SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/hadoop2/share/hadoop/mapreduce1/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
attempt_201401302213_0004_r_000000_0: SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/hadoop2/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
attempt_201401302213_0004_r_000000_0: SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/tmp/hadoop/mapred/local/taskTracker/hadoop/jobcache/job_201401302213_0004/jars/job.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
attempt_201401302213_0004_r_000000_0: SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
14/01/31 00:31:56 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201401302213_0004_r_000001_0, Status : FAILED
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Input Iterator not markable
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.MarkableIterator.<init>(MarkableIterator.java:45)
    at com.nileshc.graphfu.pagerank.Driver$MyReducer.reduce(Driver.java:185)
    at com.nileshc.graphfu.pagerank.Driver$MyReducer.reduce(Driver.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:164)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:610)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:444)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)

attempt_201401302213_0004_r_000001_0: SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
attempt_201401302213_0004_r_000001_0: SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/hadoop2/share/hadoop/mapreduce1/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
attempt_201401302213_0004_r_000001_0: SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/hadoop2/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
attempt_201401302213_0004_r_000001_0: SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/tmp/hadoop/mapred/local/taskTracker/hadoop/jobcache/job_201401302213_0004/jars/job.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
attempt_201401302213_0004_r_000001_0: SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
14/01/31 00:31:57 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0%
...
...
^C^C^C
```

**Hadoop distribution details:**
Hadoop: 2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.5.0 (from CDH4 Tarball 2.0.0-cdh4.5.0)
Output of bin/hadoop version:

```
Hadoop 2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.5.0
Subversion file:///var/lib/jenkins/workspace/CDH4.5.0-Packaging-Hadoop/build/cdh4/hadoop/2.0.0-cdh4.5.0/source/hadoop-mapreduce1-project -r Unknown
Compiled by jenkins on Wed Nov 20 14:55:43 PST 2013
From source with checksum 999ab1ceefbade5990db1ff9ce20057b
This command was run using /hadoop2/share/hadoop/mapreduce1/lib/hadoop-common-2.0.0-cdh4.5.0.jar
```

Comment: Grepcode says: 0.22.0 (http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-mapred/0.22.0/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/ReduceContext.java#ReduceContext.ValueIterator)

Comment: @ThomasJungblut thanks, but so does  2.0.0-cdh4.4.0 (http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/2.0.0-cdh4.4.0/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/ReduceContext.java?av=f) - I'm running 2.0.0-cdh4.5.0 myself, using MRv1 and not YARN. Doesn't work. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Can you please post code and stacktrace?

Comment: @ThomasJungblut just made a few edits. Please let me know if there's anything else I should add.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut, take a look at the "Something interesting" section in the question. I can't make any sense of this.

Comment: Can you verify that the class the reducer gives you is `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.ReduceContextImpl.ValueIterator`? You can check by printing `values.getClass()`

Comment: Seems strange to me, I only have access to 2.2 and the `ValueIterator` implements the interface.

Comment: Yep, `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.ReduceContextImpl.ValueIterator` it is. This is so weird.

Comment: Can you please tell me your exact version? Is it vanilla Hadoop? A link would be best. I'll just download it and setup my cluster. Such a waste of time. BTW, I really love your blog and the kind of work you do. Matches almost totally with my interest areas.

Comment: Yes, it is 2.2 the latest stable version (http://mirror.catn.com/pub/apache/hadoop/common/hadoop-2.2.0/), not sure if any Hadoop vendor also ships this yet. Thanks :)

Comment: @ThomasJungblut please check if you've any idea about this puzzler: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21468477/cant-use-compositeinputformat-with-hadoop-throwing-exception-expression-is-nul