# Can't use CompositeInputFormat with Hadoop, throwing exception Expression is null

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm using the MRv1 from CDH4 (4.5) and facing a problem with `CompositeInputFormat`. It doesn't matter how many inputs I try to join. For the sake of simplicity, here's the example with just one input:

```
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();

    Job job = new Job(conf, "Blah");
    job.setJarByClass(Blah.class);

    job.setMapperClass(Blah.BlahMapper.class);
    job.setReducerClass(Blah.BlahReducer.class);

    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(LongWritable.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(BlahElement.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(LongWritable.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(BlahElement.class);

    job.setInputFormatClass(CompositeInputFormat.class);
    String joinStatement = CompositeInputFormat.compose("inner", SequenceFileInputFormat.class, "/someinput");
    System.out.println(joinStatement);
    conf.set("mapred.join.expr", joinStatement);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(SequenceFileOutputFormat.class);

    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(newoutput));

    return job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
```

Here's the output + stacktrace:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/hadoop2/share/hadoop/mapreduce1/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/hadoop2/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
14/01/31 03:27:47 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
inner(tbl(org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.SequenceFileInputFormat,"/someinput"))
14/01/31 03:27:48 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
14/01/31 03:27:51 INFO mapred.JobClient: Cleaning up the staging area hdfs://archangel-desktop:54310/tmp/hadoop/mapred/staging/hadoop/.staging/job_201401302213_0013
14/01/31 03:27:51 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:hadoop (auth:SIMPLE) cause:java.io.IOException: Expression is null
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Expression is null
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.join.Parser.parse(Parser.java:542)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.join.CompositeInputFormat.setFormat(CompositeInputFormat.java:85)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.join.CompositeInputFormat.getSplits(CompositeInputFormat.java:127)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeNewSplits(JobClient.java:1079)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeSplits(JobClient.java:1096)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.access$600(JobClient.java:177)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:995)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:948)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:948)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:566)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:596)
    at com.nileshc.graphfu.pagerank.BlockMatVec.run(BlockMatVec.java:79)
    at com.nileshc.graphfu.Main.main(Main.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:208)
```

Anyone ever faced this before? Any ideas on how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad.

```
conf.set("mapred.join.expr", joinStatement);
```

The above should be:

```
job.getConfiguration().set("mapreduce.join.expr", joinStatement);
```

And:

```
String joinStatement = CompositeInputFormat.compose("inner", SequenceFileInputFormat.class, "/someinput");
```

^^That should be:

```
String joinStatement = CompositeInputFormat.compose("inner", SequenceFileInputFormat.class, new Path("/someinput"));
```

The first change is what made all the difference.

Answer (score 0):

In the above code,

```
conf.set("mapred.join.expr", joinStatement);
```

the above line is coded after the Job obeject is created. So its obvious that Job object does not know of this configuration!!!!!!

**See the revised code below:-**

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("mapred.join.expr", joinStatement);
Job job = new Job(conf, "Blah");
job.setJarByClass(Blah.class);
.
.
.
.
.
```

**The following is the other way around:-**

```
job.getConfiguration().set("mapreduce.join.expr", joinStatement);
```

Use the above code instead of

```
conf.set("mapred.join.expr", joinStatement);
```

Comment: Exactly. See the answer I posted above.